# What's a good way to insert very few lines of code?

Tags: listings

I know about the `listings` package, but it seems that it can't be put where I want it to be (`h` in float).

And since I just maybe want to insert exactly one line of code, I really want it to be where I put it, is there a good way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Without it, it is impossible for us to evaluate whether a given answer solves your problem or not.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1: Use the `listings` package

Simple configuration for LaTeX header (before `\begin{document}`):

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
   language=Java,
   aboveskip=3mm,
   belowskip=3mm,
   showstringspaces=false,
   columns=flexible,
   basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
   numbers=none,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   stringstyle=\color{mauve},
   breaklines=true,
   breakatwhitespace=true
   tabsize=3
   }
```

You can change default language in the middle of document with `\lstset{language=Java}`.

Example of usage in the document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  // Hello.java
  import javax.swing.JApplet;
  import java.awt.Graphics;

  public class Hello extends JApplet 
  {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.drawString("Hello, world!", 65, 95);
    }    
  }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Here's the result:

[image: a busy cat]]

### Option 2: Use the `verbatim` environment

```
\begin{verbatim}
  your
  code
  example
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: I am not sure this answer's the OP's issue. I believe his issue is about the placement of the output, not about wits formatting, though one cant tell without a MWE...

Answer (score 1):

The `numberedblock` package is intended for presenting short blocks of code.  From the package's usage example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{numberedblock}

\begin{document}

\parindent 0.3in
%\setlength\maxblocklabelsize{-.4in}
\setlength\blockindent{0.0in}

This is a test of the \textsf{numberedblock} style packcage, which is
specially designed to produce sequentially numbered BLOCKS of code (note
the individual code lines are not numbered, but the whole block gets a
single number, for later reference (much in the same way that equations
can get numbered in a document).  While specialized for numbering code
blocks, the commands can actually number other items, as well, in fact
anything that fits in a \LaTeX{} box.

If the code block contains no special characters, one can simply use the
command form, called \verb,\numblock,.  It cannot handle verbatim text,
but must use standard \LaTeX{} escape sequences (for line breaks,
contiguous spaces, special characters, etc.).  It puts the output in a
tt font , which is the same used in the verbatim environment:

\numblock{This text is the\\argument to the command\\where double
slashes have been\\used for line breaks}

Most useful, however, there is also the \verb,numVblock, environment,
which handles verbatim text, as seen in the next example:

\begin{numVblock}
This is the numVblock 
environment, which         (<--see contiguous spaces here)
succeeds in
incorporating verbatim text like
@##$%*$%$()||}{?><\\    \end{numVblock}

As envisioned the \verb,numVblock, environment would be ideally suited
for displaying small code blocks as part of documentation.  The code can
contain contiguous spaces and special characters:

\begin{numVblock}
      program test
      implicit none
      integer a, x
c$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
      a = 0
      x = 1
   10 a = a + x
      if (a .eq. 100) stop
      goto 10
      end
\end{numVblock}

Below, I test the \verb,\numblock, command with the argument as a
box, rather than as formatted text.

\numblock{\fbox{Testing, 1,2,3 testing a box}}

Don't forget, there are settable parameters to define the block
left-indent, the format of the label, and (if needed) the labels' max
width/placement.

\end{document}
```

[image]